# Cannot get object from database

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I just want to retrieve an object from the database, that realise my query, but i get exception.

```
@Override
public Tache getLastSousTache() {
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String sql = "select * from tache where idtache=(select max(idTache) from tache where soustache is not null)";
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    Tache tache = new Tache();
    tache = (Tache) query.uniqueResult();
    return tache;
}
```

I got this exception :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.model.Tache
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Comment: Why the `new Tache()`? It doesn't make sense. Is `Tache` a POJO managed by Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to initialize your class Tache?

Does it work if you just say:

Tache tache = null;
tache = (Tache) query.uniqueResult();

so without coding:

Tache tache = new Tache();

Comment: Still have the same exception

Comment: I assume you're using Native SQL in Hibernate, but it's somewhat different to HQL.

You're using idtache in your sql query, but 'idtache' is not set as a parameter.  Also adding your class to the query is a good idea.

Comment: Without Native SQL it's something like:

@Override
public Tache getLastSousTache(long myTacheid) {
    Session session =    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Tache tache = null;
    String queryString = "from Tache where id = :id";
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setLong("id", myTacheid);
    tache = (Tache) query.uniqueResult();
    return tache;
}

You're sqlquery is a bit different, so you have to look it up ...